# In a browser extension, how do I click a specific button of an alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So...

I need to click `[Stay on this page]` automatically in such a prompt:

> Confirm navigation: [Leave this page] [Stay on this page]

The code that invokes this is

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
  return 'Leave page?';
  //Click prompt code goes here.
  $(window).unbind();
});
```

If I take away `return 'Leave page?';` 
then the iframed page overrides the top frame and the user is struck with an unknown site, maybe there's another way to do this?

Comment: excuse me, for me your question is not so clear...

Comment: @Reigel: I think the OP wants to automatically click a button in an `alert` popup: *I need to **auto-click "stay"** on this page in such a prompt: "Confirm navigation: [Leave this page] [Stay on this page]"* edited it to make it more clear.

Comment: I changed the title to reflect the question

Comment: @mplungjan: I would not say it is a "jQuery alert". That could be misleading. He wants to *use* jQuery to click such a button.

Comment: that is not likely since the built-in alert cannot be manipulated by script and the buttons are `Cancel` and `OK`

Answer (score 0):

Actually that would hook into the `onbeforeunload` event:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
      return 'Leave page?';
});
```

Comment: You are good! I didn't think that had too much to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of automatically clicking it, check if you can automatically disable `window.onbeforeunload` event handlers. That's most likely much easier than trying to send a click to a specific button in a modal window anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Thiefmaster.
Alternative is to replace the alert, prompt or confirm if that is what is used:

```
window.confirm=function() {
  // here you do what you want
}
```

Comment: For all curious, http://bit.ly/SweetSearch4 is the chrome ext. in mind. It helps you search really efficiently by keeping your results on the left and loading them on the right; in an iframe.